# Can you assign a background image per camera?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Quick question that I don't see an exact answer to, but is there a way to lock a background image to be displayed when a certain camera is set (<kbd>Ctrl+0</kbd>) as the camera?

I have several cameras when looking through, line up my reference with my geometry.  I'd like it to automatically use "reference001.jpg" when "Camera 1" is activated (and looking through it).  Then, if I activate "Camera 2" as the active camera (and look through it) it displays "reference002.jpg" and so on.

Right now I just have 5 different background images assigned to camera view, and have to disable the current one and enable the one I want (the little eye icon).  Just wondering if there's a better way.  Thanks!

Comment: There isn't a way. Each 3dviewport saves it's own background image settings, so you could setup five different views with different backgrounds. I think it might be something that could be added to the [stored views addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/stored_views).